# Where to find web-standard fonts for Ubuntu?

Tags: fonts

I would like to put these fonts: http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/WindowsMacFonts.html.

In my .fonts folder of my Ubuntu server (Heroku).

Where can I find these in a way that they are available for Ubuntu and so I can put them in my .fonts folder and push it to Heroku?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are asking for this: http://www.apaddedcell.com/web-fonts

Comment: Nice. But there is no link for download right?

Comment: they seem that they are already installed. Browers may accept them without calling them into your html head from a folder. just type **font:** and your font you want in css file. Try it with a test.html

Comment: I'm using Heroku server and they are not installed there. That's why I want to put them in my .fonts folder and push into the remote server...

Comment: I don't know this server but you can try from an other way like dropbox link or something else to put them there

Comment: GeoMind. How can I put them there if I don't know where to download them from? My question is, where can I find those fonts for Ubuntu? Or can I use the Windows version?

Comment: I think that they are the same files in ubuntu and windows. try it and tell me.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable the multiverse in your repositories, you can then run

```
sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts
```

This will install core MS TTF fonts such as Arial, Comic Sans, Courier New, Georgia, Times New Roman, Trebuchet, Verdana etc

Comment: I guess I cannot do that on Heroku. I specifically need to have a .fonts folder in my application with all the fonts, and push it to Heroku.